# Error in ionic2 when JSON data is not present

Tags: json, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I made an API which takes db data and passes JSON data to ionic2 app.The data may have data accordingly to what key is sent by the user.So all the data may not be present for all users at the same time and that's why i have written a common code for all the users. My issue is when data node is not present in JSON file then the page breaks saying "undefined" object. How do i solve this?

**Typescript Method**

```js
displayData()
  {
    if(this.responseDetails[0].DocumentTypeDetails.Deed.Checked)
    this.showDeed= this.responseDetails[0].DocumentTypeDetails.Deed.Checked=="True"?1:0;
    if(this.responseDetails[0].DocumentTypeDetails.Amend.Checked)
    this.showAmend=this.responseDetails[0].DocumentTypeDetails.Amend.Checked=="True"?1:0;
    if(this.responseDetails[0].DocumentTypeDetails.MortgageDeed.Checked)
    this.showMortDeed=this.responseDetails[0].DocumentTypeDetails.MortgageDeed.Checked=="True"?1:0;
    if(this.responseDetails[0].DocumentTypeDetails.MortgageRefi.Checked)
    this.showMortRefi=this.responseDetails[0].DocumentTypeDetails.MortgageRefi.Checked=="True"?1:0;
    if(this.responseDetails[0].DocumentTypeDetails.MortgageMod.Checked)
    this.showMortMod=this.responseDetails[0].DocumentTypeDetails.MortgageMod.Checked=="True"?1:0;
    if(this.responseDetails[0].DocumentTypeDetails.Assignment.Checked)
    this.showAssign=this.responseDetails[0].DocumentTypeDetails.Assignment.Checked=="True"?1:0;
    if(this.responseDetails[0].DocumentTypeDetails.ReleaseSatisfaction.Checked)
    this.showRelSatisfaction=this.responseDetails[0].DocumentTypeDetails.ReleaseSatisfaction.Checked=="True"?1:0;
    if(this.responseDetails[0].DocumentTypeDetails.poa.Checked)
    this.showPOA=this.responseDetails[0].DocumentTypeDetails.poa.Checked=="True"?1:0;
    }
```

**JSON**

```js
"DocumentTypeDetails": {
            "PageRec": "AL005",
            "State": "AL",
            "County": "Autauga County",
            "CityTown": null,
            "Zip": null,
            "ShowRecordingInfo": "true",
            "Deed": {
                "Checked": "True",
                "Pages": "1",
                "ConsiderationAmount": "150000"
            },
            "MortgageDeed": {
                "Checked": "False",
                "Pages": null,
                "NewDebtAmount": null
            },
            "MortgageRefi": {
                "Checked": "False",
                "Pages": null,
                "NewDebtAmount": null,
                "OriginalDebt": null,
                "UnpaidDebt": null
            },
            "Assignment": {
                "Checked": "False",
                "Pages": null,
                "Assignments": null
            },
            "ReleaseSatisfaction": {
                "Checked": "False",
                "Pages": null,
                "ReleasesSatisfactions": null
            }
            }
```

Here in JSON file we don't have all the data for this user but for another one some of the missing data might be present.Is there any check for this?

**More to Typescript file**

```js
 private responseUrl='http://localhost:58682/home/index1';

   getresponseDetails(){
        return    this.http.get(this.responseUrl).map(res=>res.json());
    }


     LoadResponseData(){
      this.service.getresponseDetails()
      .subscribe(data=>{
        this.responseDetails=data;
      }
```

**Error**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Checked' of undefined
    at CalculatePage.displayData (calculate.ts:186)
    at CalculatePage.ngOnInit1 (calculate.ts:111)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (calculate.ts:93)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:234)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:183)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:83)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1205)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you check if the node you are looking for is in the response as you receive it?

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
makeGetRequest() {
    this.http.get("https://api.mywebsite.com/users/1454")
    .subscribe(response => {
        let resJson = JSON.parse(response);
        if (resJson['Amend'] === undefined) {
            Observable.throw('no Amend node in received response');
        }
        this.responseDetails = resJson;
    }, error => {
        console.log('oops!');
    });
}
```

Comment: but if it throws the error at the check when will it load all the remaining data ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you edit your post and include an example of correct response and erroneous response, pointing out what the problem in the second case is?

Comment: In the JSON data "Amend" is not present that's why when i try to fetch the .checked data from it , the undefined error will be thrown ...

Comment: For now i resolved the issue with a temporary fix...checked every element if it were undefined or not ...this worked fine but its not a good approach

Comment: Check my updated code above `if (resJson['Amend'] === undefined) { ...}`

Comment: Yes if i check it with the specific element then it will work fine...but that would be a bad approach...checking each and every specific node...There must be bypass for that

Comment: If the json response schema is not defined and set in stone (e.g. some fields may be missing sometimes, but you cannot know when), the only way is to do check if the field is undefined, before you check each field. Another way you would do that that may be cleaner define better schemas that always return what you expect.

Comment: For example you can have a general schema `User`, another `Teacher` and `Student` that contain all the fields of user + some more that are specific to the type. Then you can have a single field `user: "student" or user: "teacher"` If student u know what other fields are in there.

Comment: Then that means i have to make changes in API as i am blindly converting Xml into JSON and returning that here...@maninak You know most of my scenerios :)

Comment: Yup... Friendly advice, keep away from xml responses, they are slow to transmit and slower to parse via javascript. Use JSON instead if you can. Cheers!